# Save and load multiple values with title

Tags: vb.net, save, load, external

I am using Visual Studio Express 2012.

I would like to let my program save and load data into only ONE additional data file (txt, csv, dll or something else) in the following format (just an example, doesn't have to be exact this one, its just to show you).

```
[Title1]
Value1
Value2
Value3
Value4

[Title2]
Value1
Value2
Value3
Value4
```

The programm is built up like this:
As soon as the Form is loaded, Combobox1 will be filled with all the titles in the brackets "[]" (Title1, Title2 etc)

If you select one then the 4 Labels will be filled with the values.

```
Label1 = Value1 | Label2 = Value2 | Label3 = Value3 | Label4 = Value4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example using a Class to hold the Title/Values and an XmlSerializer to read/write an XML file.  Instances of the Class are held in a List.

Here's the code:

```
Public Class Form1

    <Serializable> _
    Public Class TitleGroup

        Public Title As String
        Public Value1 As String
        Public Value2 As String
        Public Value3 As String
        Public Value4 As String

        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return Title
        End Function

    End Class

    Private TitleGroups As New List(Of TitleGroup)
    Private DataFile As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Data.xml")

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        LoadXmlData()
    End Sub

    Private Sub LoadXmlData()
        If System.IO.File.Exists(DataFile) Then
            Try
                Dim xml As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(TitleGroups.GetType)
                Using fs As New System.IO.FileStream(DataFile, IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)
                    TitleGroups = DirectCast(xml.Deserialize(fs), List(Of TitleGroup))
                End Using
                ComboBox1.DataSource = Nothing
                ComboBox1.DataSource = TitleGroups
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString, "Error Loading XML Data")
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
            Dim TG As TitleGroup = ComboBox1.SelectedItem
            Label1.Text = TG.Value1
            Label2.Text = TG.Value2
            Label3.Text = TG.Value3
            Label4.Text = TG.Value4
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        SaveXmlData()
    End Sub

    Private Sub SaveXmlData()
        Try
            Dim xml As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(TitleGroups.GetType)
            Using fs As New System.IO.FileStream(DataFile, IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, IO.FileAccess.Write)
                xml.Serialize(fs, TitleGroups)
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString, "Error Saving XML Data")
        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```

and here's an example XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfTitleGroup xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <TitleGroup>
    <Title>Pets</Title>
    <Value1>Dog</Value1>
    <Value2>Cat</Value2>
    <Value3>Fish</Value3>
    <Value4>Hamster</Value4>
  </TitleGroup>
  <TitleGroup>
    <Title>Languages</Title>
    <Value1>C#</Value1>
    <Value2>VB.Net</Value2>
    <Value3>Java</Value3>
    <Value4>Objective-C</Value4>
  </TitleGroup>
</ArrayOfTitleGroup>
```