# Get variable for two clicks on form

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to assign two clicks to two variables on my Mouse_Down event on my form. Here is the starting code I am working with on Mouse_Down event. What I am trying to do is click two points on a form, get the X & Y location (these will then give me my button size). Example: First Click get X & Y, Second Click get X & Y then perform click of a button.... repeat this until I quit.

```
 Private Sub Form1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseDown

    Dim XYClickOne, XYClickTwo
    Dim count As Integer
    count = 0

    Do
        XYClickOne = e.X & "," & e.Y
        XYClickTwo = e.X & "," & e.Y
        count = count + 1
    Loop Until count = 2

    Button1.PerformClick()  'After 2nd click, create button.

End Sub
```

Comment: Look into variable scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move those variables out to Form level so they are accessible by other methods, and will persist across clicks.  Here's a quick example:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private points(2) As Point
    Private count As Integer = 0

    Private Sub Form1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseDown
        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
            points(count) = New Point(e.X, e.Y)
            count = count + 1
            If count = 2 Then
                count = 0
                CreateButton(points(0), points(1))
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub CreateButton(ByVal ptA As Point, ByVal ptB As Point)
        Dim pt As New Point(Math.Min(ptA.X, ptB.X), Math.Min(ptA.Y, ptB.Y))
        Dim sz As New Size(Math.Abs(ptA.X - ptB.X) + 1, Math.Abs(ptA.Y - ptB.Y) + 1)
        Dim btn As New Button
        btn.Bounds = New Rectangle(pt, sz)
        btn.Text = "X"
        Me.Controls.Add(btn)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thank You once again Idle_Mind. This is EXACTLY what I was looking for, this will most certainly get me going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Thought you might like a quick example of making a "rubber band selection".  Click and DRAG on your form with the left mouse button:

The artifacts are from my screen recorder, in reality it drew smoothly with out leaving lines behind:

[image]

Code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private ptA, ptB As Point
    Private count As Integer = 0
    Private firstBoxDrawn As Boolean = False

    Private Sub Form1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseDown
        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
            ptA = Me.PointToScreen(New Point(e.X, e.Y))
            ptB = ptA
            firstBoxDrawn = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove
        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
            If firstBoxDrawn Then
                ' erase the previous box by drawing it again
                ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(RectangleFromPoints(ptA, ptB), Color.Black, FrameStyle.Dashed)
            End If
            ptB = Me.PointToScreen(New Point(e.X, e.Y))
            ' draw the new box
            ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(RectangleFromPoints(ptA, ptB), Color.Black, FrameStyle.Dashed)
            firstBoxDrawn = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseUp
        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
            ' erase the box
            ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(RectangleFromPoints(ptA, ptB), Color.Black, FrameStyle.Dashed)
            CreateButton(Me.PointToClient(ptA), Me.PointToClient(ptB))
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub CreateButton(ByVal ptA As Point, ByVal ptB As Point)
        Dim btn As New Button
        btn.Text = "X"
        btn.Bounds = RectangleFromPoints(ptA, ptB)
        Me.Controls.Add(btn)
    End Sub

    Private Function RectangleFromPoints(ByVal ptA As Point, ByVal ptB As Point) As Rectangle
        Dim pt As New Point(Math.Min(ptA.X, ptB.X), Math.Min(ptA.Y, ptB.Y))
        Dim sz As New Size(Math.Abs(ptA.X - ptB.X) + 1, Math.Abs(ptA.Y - ptB.Y) + 1)
        Return New Rectangle(pt, sz)
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Ok Idle_Mind, I think I'm going crazy. This is even better than what I was thinking. I am going to try this out right now and I will get back to you. Thanks so much for your help and your time.

Comment: No problem.  Currently it lets you drag whenever you want, but you could just create another boolean variable at Form level that you toggle to true only when the user should be able to drag a button.  You could toggle that boolean flag from a button, for instance.  Let me know if you need help with that simple change.

Comment: This is very cool Idle_Mind. If I fill the form with buttons, how would I then save all the buttons as they were created?

Comment: Save them so they could be re-created on a future run?

Comment: Well basically if I were to use this is a type of template. I create a form of various button sizes, then save that form with all buttons that were created so I can do something else with them.  This would go along with my other post where I am creating button names from an external text file.

Comment: Each button could be represented by a Rectangle, so you could declare a `List(Of Rectangle)` at Form level and then add each button's rectangle to that as they are created.  You could then save that list to an XML file using [XmlSerialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=netcore-3.1).  If you want to be able to save other things about each button, like the text, color, etc., then you'd create a CUSTOM CLASS representing that infomation, then change the `List()` to be of that type instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217843/discussion-between-noob2java-and-idle-mind).

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out and see where it takes me. I will read up on the XMLSerialization and give that a try. It sounds like this could be much more efficient for my project. I will let you know if I come into any issues. Thanks so much again, this is a huge learning experience for me.

Comment: [Here's some example code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17097551/2330053) to get you started.

Comment: Hopefully someone like Idle_Mind is watching today... I am trying to start a small project based on this. I am stuck on how I need to save a button that was created by the dragging method? I'm not sure what the control is named or how to save back to the XML file.  Could someone show me an example of how to do this?  Basically I will drag to create many buttons, save them and load the next time I open the project.  Thanks

Comment: Where are you at currently?  Do you have a `List(Of Rectangle)`?  XmlSerialization working?

Comment: I can load the XML file that you created and I can create the buttons using the drag method that you posted. That is all I have, now I just don't know how to actually save what is being created.

Comment: So in the other example, I created a custom class to hold Strings.  Have you changed it to hold two Points instead?  Then when you create each button, you also create an instance of the custom class, populate it, and add it to your List.

Comment: Idle_Mind, I am using your drag method to create the buttons. I am unclear about the custom class. If you see my newest post, I am getting a bit closer with using the xml file.

Comment: I just removed the last post as I am looking more into the xml usage.

Comment: How can I make the drag method work on a panel?

Comment: Change all the events after the `Handles` clauses from `Me.xxx` to `Panel1.xxx`, then change `Me.Controls.Add()` to `Panel1.Controls.Add()`.  You also have to change the `PointToXXX` calls from `Me` to `Panel1`.